# WordPress version update confusion

Tags: wordpress

Recently I have Wordpress version to 4.9.4 and my existing website was running on 4.7.4.
My Query is Display Posts Shortcode plug-in is compatible up to 4.8.4. If I update to WordPress version 4.9.4 does it create any issues.?

Comment: Common programming practise is test first in a sandpit environment.

Answer (score 0):

Having WordPress plugin incompatible with WordPress versions often create unnecessary issues.

It would be better to wait for the new version of the plugin that is compatible with the new version of the WordPress.

You can also check the Github Documentation of that plugin if it is available on Github or raise a ticket on their website.

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

usually no major changes accrue in core files of wordpress when you update to newer version and it always work fine but it is recommended to have a database backup before updating to new version.

Answer (score 0):

Well written plugins rarely break with a new version of WordPress. I generally install new versions of WordPress as soon as they are released.

That said, the best practice is to install the new version of anything (WordPress core, plugins, themes) on a test version of your site before installing on your live site.

Also, you should have reliable backups in place, and know how to restore from them quickly if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as too long for comment:

Most plugins are compatible with later WP versions than "tested to" indicates. Plugin authors (including me) do not spend time modifying the "tested to WP version" whenever a new version of WP is released; but only update this detail when they make changes to the code.

Normally the best place for an answer should be at the [the plugin's support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/display-posts-shortcode) but as the author failed to reply to a query about compatibility with 4.9.1 you'll probably get no help there.

Educated guess is that it is compatible. Plugin has over 100k users, but [other than this question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-parent-stops-working/)  (user does not identify WP version, no author response, maybe user specific?) the support forum has no recent posts about the plugin being broken; and later posts with questions about functionality are by people using WP 4.9.4 implying it is working for them.

If I was in your shoes (and didn't have a separate test site) I would risk the Wordpress update. Additionally for security it is always wise to have an up to date version of Wordpress ([4.7.4. known vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/version_id-213652/Wordpress-Wordpress-4.7.4.html)).